# I have created a Bio application in django.. how could i stop user to create duplicate Bio or remove create Bio button

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Here is my model

```
class Bio(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="",null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)    
    text = models.TextField(max_length=280)
    facebook = models.URLField(name='facebook',default=None,null=True)
    linkdin = models.URLField(name='linkdin',default=None,null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="bios/images", default="")    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my views

```
class BioCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
template_name = 'bios/bio_form.html'
form_class = BioForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('bios:all')
def get(self, request, pk=None) :
    form = BioForm()
    ctx = { 'form': form }
    return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

def post(self, request, pk=None) :
    form = BioForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)

    if not form.is_valid() :
        ctx = {'form' : form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

    # Add owner to the model before saving
    pic = form.save(commit=False)
    pic.owner = self.request.user
    pic.save()
    return redirect(self.success_url)
```

here is my nav bar pic [This the pic of Nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WB7y.png)

here is template
`

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bios:all' %}">Bios of seniors</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bios:bio_create' %}">CREATE Bio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bios:intrest_create' %}">CREATE Intrest</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bios:project_create' %}">CREATE Project</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">LOGOUT</a></li>
      {% else %}
      
      {% endif %}
    </ul>

  </div>
```

How can I stop the user to create duplicate Bio or remove that create bio button

I already assigned an owner to that bio

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of the template.

Comment: added some template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model it with a `OneToOneField` to restrict the database from having multiple `Bio` objects for the same user. This at least will enforce data integrity. It does not make much sense either to pass a `default=''`, since this fields stores in the database a primary key of the related user model. Finally using `null=True` might not be a good idea, since that means you could create a `Bio` object that is not linked to any user:

```
class Bio(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

You can remove a lot of boilerplate code by using a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView). This is a `View`, but with extra logic to make it more convenient to use a `ModelForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class BioCreateView(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'bios/bio_form.html'
    form_class = BioForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('bios:all')

    def test_func(self):
        try:
            self.request.user.bio
            return False
        except AttributeError:
            return True

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here the `test_function` will ensure that you can only access the view (both GET and POST request), if the user has no `Bio` object filled in. The `form_valid` method patches the `instance` wrapped in the form, and sets the `.owner` to the logged in user.

But this will of course not restrict the template from rendering the link. You can however restrict this with an `{% if … %}` condition:

```
{% if not user.bio %}
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bios:bio_create' %}">CREATE Bio</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: please see some more info Actually I got an answer to my old query

Comment: @JayantJaiswal: this logic is in the `form_valid` of the `CreateView`. Please do not use `commit=False`, it will no longer save many-to-many fields in the form, if you later add these.